# How to stop Service using Alarm Manager at a particular time in Android?

Tags: android

In my app i want to stop the service in a particular time using Alarm Manager. But Alarm Manager cancel() method is not taking any time. So how can i stop it?

I wrote the code like below:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardScreen.this, ServiceClass.class);
    Log.d("Testing", "Intent created");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(DashboardScreen.this, req, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm_manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(),30*1000, pi);
    Log.d("Testing", "Intent created");
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ServiceClass.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(this, req, intent1, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```

Comment: Can anyone know the answer?? How to stop that pending intent?? Please help....

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you cannot stop a service using alarmmanager in a direct way. cancel() function in alarmmanager is just to remove the scheduled repeating alarm.

I suggest you to call an activity which stops your service using another alarm manager when needed:

alarmmanager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+TIME_PERIOD,pendingIntent);

If you want to stop your service after 600 seconds, you can set TIME_PERIOD to 600*1000.
pendingIntent is for activity that stops your service.